# Specify currently grabbed records within Model class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activerecord-relation

I have a class method where I want to modify the records that are currently grabbed by an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.  But I don't know how to refer to the current scope in a class method.  `self` does not do it.

Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def self.modify_those_records
    #thought implicitly #to_a would be called on currently grabbed records but doesn't work
    temp_users_to_a = to_a
    ...
  end
end
```

I would use it like this:

```
User.some_scope.modify_those_records
```

So `User.some_scope` would return to me an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that contains a bunch of `User` records.  I then want to modify those records within that class method and then return them.

Problem is: I don't know how to explicitly refer to "that group of records" within a class method.

Comment: Try using `current_scope.to_a`

Comment: What do you mean by "grabbed"?

Comment: @MrYoshiji Excellent!  Thank you.  Do provide an answer so that I can give you credit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `current_scope`:

```
def self.modify_those_records
  current_scope.each do |user|
    user.do_something!
  end
end
```

---

If you want to order Users based on their admin rights, you would be better to use ActiveRecord:

```
scope :order_admins_first, order('CASE WHEN is_admin = true THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, id')
User.some_scope.order_admins_first
```

This code implies that you have a boolean column `is_admin` on the users table.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that a combination of a scope with `each` and an instance method is easier to understand than a class method. And as a bonus it is easier to test, because you can test all steps in isolation:

Therefore instead of `User.some_scope.modify_those_records` I would do something like:

```
User.some_scope.each(&:modify)
```

and implement a instance method:

```
# in user.rb
def modify
  # whatever needs to be done
end
```

Comment: The current thing I'm trying to do is this: If a group of users has an admin user: then pluck it out and then push it onto the front.  I'm not sure if I can do that with an instance method.  I think I would need to do that with a class   method which changes the activerecord to an array, does that business and then returns the array (or converts it back to an active record relation again).  But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Neil you can give users a sort field, 1 for admin, 0 for others and sort by descending of that, no need to fetch all records (as this may break pagination)

Comment: @Neil: How do you identify admin users? Do they have a boolean flag?

Comment: @spickermann I was able to figure it out.  I just did a sort because as you guessed there is an admin boolean.  That way I didn't have to worry about modifying the activerecord object.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to modify the order of the records - better way is to add a sort field (if you do not have it already) to the model and sort by that.

```
User.some_scope.order(name: :asc).order(is_admin: :desc)
```